# Python3 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) even when three values are assigned

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a image analysis project. encountering this error and not sure hot to solve it , cuz the function 'detect_balls' returns three values but couldn't assign it to variables whre it is called out to . Would really appriciate your help . the code is attached below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import time
bgr_color = 29,2,128 #129,119,195
color_threshold = 50 #color range

hsv_color = cv2.cvtColor( np.uint8([[bgr_color]] ), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[0][0]
HSV_lower = np.array([hsv_color[0] - color_threshold, hsv_color[1] - color_threshold, hsv_color[2] - color_threshold])
HSV_upper = np.array([hsv_color[0] + color_threshold, hsv_color[1] + color_threshold, hsv_color[2] + color_threshold])


def detect_ball(frame):
    x, y, radius = -1, -1, -1

    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, HSV_lower, HSV_upper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=1)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=1)

    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    center = (-1, -1)

    
    if len(contours) > 0:
       
        c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(mask)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])) #position of the ball

        if radius > 10:
            #outline ball
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            #show ball center
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    return center[0], center[1], radius


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = '/home/venkat-com/Desktop/track/golf01_preview.mp4'

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)

    dist = []
    times = []
    count = 0
    kalmanFilter = []
    variance = []
    initialEstimatedVariance = 1
    deltaX = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    deltat = 524  
    noise = 1  
    sensorCovariance = 83791.65209996712



    variance.append(initialEstimatedVariance)
 
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        count+=1
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        #detect_ball(frame)
        [x,y,r] = detect_ball(frame)
        if (len(dist) != 0):
            x_prev = dist[len(dist) - 1]

            velocity = float(deltaX)/deltat

            dist.append(x)

            estimatedX = x_prev + velocity
            estimatedVariance = variance[len(variance)-1] + noise

            kalmanGain = float(estimatedVariance)/(estimatedVariance + sensorCovariance)

            kalmanPosition = estimatedX + (kalmanGain*(x - estimatedX))

            kalmanFilter.append(kalmanPosition)

            updatedVariance = estimatedVariance-(kalmanGain*estimatedVariance)
            variance.append(updatedVariance)

            print (kalmanFilter)
            #print(variance)

        else: #don't do any calculations on the 1st point
            x_initial = detect_ball(frame)[0]
            dist.append(x_initial)
            kalmanFilter.append(x_initial)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  # Create window with freedom of dimensions
        imS = cv2.resizeWindow('frame', (960, 540))  # Resize image

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Tried to check the values given out by the function, and all of them were correct and no null values

This is the terminal's output trying to run the code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/venkat-com/trajectory.py", line 67, in <module>
    [x,y,r] = detect_ball(frame)
  File "/home/venkat-com/trajectory.py", line 22, in detect_ball
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: [tour], [ask]. you are expected to look for existing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.findCountours` seems to return only two values, `contours` and `hierarchy` as per the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). You need to remove im2 from that line.